# Error 0x6700 in securechannel.processSecurity(apdu)

Tags: javacard

I want to generate gp secure channel 01. my trace is:

```
Send: 80 50 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Recv: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 02 00 02 0E 5A 8F F4 57 DD 35 5C 49 A6 8B 15 E9 A5 9000
```

so I have :

```
Card challenge= 00 02 0E 5A 8F F4 57 DD
Host challenge=00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

according SPC01: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xulu.png)

```
Derivation data== 8F F4 57 DD 00 00 00 00 00 02 0E 5A 00 00 00 00
IV=0000000000000000
c_ENC: 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
```

according this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkinF.png)  and 3Des online

### session s_ENC=  C72F032C8BAD55D4D2579295CCF0A6CA

now :

```
hot-auth_data = card challenge + host challenge + pad
host-auth=  00020E5A8FF457DD00000000000000008000000000000000
s_ENC=C72F032C8BAD55D4D2579295CCF0A6CA
IV=0000000000000000
 ===========
result=  93CC77E144488A031BFFCCC62EB3B5C233A485F8255FE90E
Host cryptogram= 33A485F8255FE90E
```

but when I send :
 848200000833A485F8255FE90E
 I have error 0x6700 in method SDInstruction in line 
 short len = sc.processSecurity(apdu);

```
    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
    if (selectingApplet()) {
        return;
    }


    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

            case ISO7816.INS_SELECT:
                select();
            return;

            case INS_INIT_UPDATE:
            case INS_EXT_AUTH:
                 SDInstruction(apdu);
                 break;
            }
 }

 private void SDInstruction(APDU apdu) 
{
    byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
    byte cla = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA];
    byte ins = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

    apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    if(ins == INS_INIT_UPDATE)
        sc = GPSystem.getSecureChannel();

    short len = sc.processSecurity(apdu);

    apdu.setOutgoing();
    apdu.setOutgoingLength(len);
    apdu.sendBytes(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short) len);        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your card is using `SCP02` and not `SCP01`.

Given the response to the `INITIALIZE UPDATE` command:

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 **FF 02** 00 02 0E 5A 8F F4 57 DD 35 5C 49 A6 8B 15 E9 A5 9000

The highlighted part is the *"Key Information"* which contains:

- *"Key Version Number"* -- in your trace `0xFF`
- *"Secure Channel Protocol Identifier"* -- in your trace it is `0x02` indicating `SCP02`

See the [Global Platform Card Specification](http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp) for further reference (sections describing the `INITIALIZE UPDATE` command).

So you need to establish the secure channel with the card according to the `SCP02`.

---

Some additional (random) notes:

- be sure to check the `"i"` secure channel parameter encoded inside the *"Card Recognition Data"* (tag `'64'`) as well
- you might want to look at the method [GlobalPlatform.openSecureChannel()](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/7e621555a3d2d74dd2ba5b935e670a6403c1c050/src/pro/javacard/gp/GlobalPlatform.java#L451) and the inner class [GlobalPlatform.SCP0102Wrapper](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/7e621555a3d2d74dd2ba5b935e670a6403c1c050/src/pro/javacard/gp/GlobalPlatform.java#L1073) in the [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) tool source code

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

According to the [GlobalPlatform specification](http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp), the EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE command has to include the host cryptogram as well as the MAC. Both are 8 bytes long, hence, your command should be 16 bytes in total.

If you want to implement the generation of this MAC value yourself, you can follow the description in the GlobalPlatform spec. But I suggest you to make use of available open source implementation. For example: [GPJ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gpj/) is a Java implementation of the GlobalPlatform specification and has all commands that you need. You can take a look at the class GlobalPlatformService, where you will find the implementation of the secure channel protocol. GPDroid (github.com/mobilesec/secure-element-gpdroid) is a wrapper for this project on Android.

Comment: Thanks in Advance. Excuse me.... I read gp specification but I can't understand how to generate MAC? 1-  I should generate Mac for command "8482010010" + "cardcahhlenfe" + "800000". Is it correct? 2- which tools can i use for generate mac ? I searched for online tools but I can not find. 3- I downloaded  GPj but I don't know how to use it? I use pyaapdutool to send command to card and don't have android app now

Comment: Excuse me ..I should say my real card supports spc01 . and this post was for a virtual card. i  should work  with spc01

Comment: 1 - not sure what the question is, but if you are asking if you need to generate a MAC for the second command: then, yes
2 & 3 - I don't know of any tool that only generates MAC, but you use GPJ for that. In the Method "wrap" of the class GlobalPlatformService you will also find one implementation of the SCP1 and SCP2 MAC computation. GPJ also comes with the capability to use it on the command line. Just take a look into the main method to see how to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much dear miho